What is this light green tumor on my flaming katy?
I recently discovered a light green growth on one of the stalks of my flaming katy:

It is hard to the touch and dry. No insects can be discovered on the plant. So what could that be? And should I somehow treat it or just let it be?

I can't find an exact matching image, but looking for things that cause issues with kalanchoes, "crown gall" seems most likely.
Gall is a common term for weird lumps in plants, often caused by insects. In this case, not an insect, but a bacterium - if that's what this is. The one pictured looks "more advanced" at a guess, but I'm not finding many images (so I don't know how it looks over time, really.)

Image Source
That's caused by Agrobacterium tumefaciens that lives in the soil, and is described as "difficult to eradicate."
If you prune it out, be sure to sterilize your pruning tools to avoid spreading it.
